# Prefer const literals to create immutables classes

Tags: flutter

I get an error :

> prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables

on this widget:

```
 child: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
         Hyperlink('https://t.me/egorka', 'chat with me'),
     ],
 ),
```

where class Hyperlink is defined like:

```
class Hyperlink extends StatelessWidget {
  const Hyperlink(this._url, this._text);

  final String _url;
  final String _text;
```

I can't figure out how to change the code to get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is absolutely fine .But remove the `const` keyword from the constructor.

Answer (score 5):

jump to file `analysis_options.yaml` add this code `prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables: false` below property `rules :` then  `Ctrl+s`

---

example :

```
rules:
prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables: false
prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables: false
prefer_const_constructors: false
file_names: false
```

Answer (score 1):

another solution

```dart
child: Column(
     children: <Widget> const[
         Hyperlink('https://t.me/egorka', 'chat with me'),
     ], <enter code here>
 ),
```